# Joining two sql tables on a matching column

Tags: postgresql

I have two sql tables,

**table_1** looks like this:

```
datestamp       items

2020-01-01      1
2020-01-01      33
2020-01-01      245
2020-01-01      55
2020-01-01      534
2020-01-01      35
2020-01-01      35
2020-01-02      10
2020-01-02      100
2020-01-02      50
2020-01-02      10
2020-01-02      1
2020-01-02      166
2020-01-02      76
2020-01-02      67
```

**table_2** looks like this:

```
datestamp       items_2

2020-01-01      346
2020-01-01      3623
2020-01-02      63
2020-01-02      73
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

- Group items by datestamp for both tables
- Join the tables on a datestamp
- Create another column which would be items - items_2
- Make it all as a view

What I have tried:

```
select datestamp, SUM(items) from table_1 group by datestamp

select datestamp, SUM(items_2) from table_2 group by datestamp
```

And it returns what is expected ( numbers are dummy ):

```
2020-01-01  132
2020-01-02  432
2020-01-03  353


2020-01-01  563
2020-01-02  236
2020-01-03  364
```

When I try to join the tables:

```
select table_1.datestamp, table_1.SUM(items), table_2.SUM(items_2)
from table_1
left join table_2
on table_1.datestamp = table_2.datestamp
```

I get:

> Invalid operation: schema "table_1" does not exist

The output I am looking for would look like this ( numbers are dummy ):

```
datestamp       items_1_sum     items_2_sum     difference

2020-01-01      346             525             items_2_sum-items_1_sum
2020-01-02      3623            352             63  
2020-01-03      63              52              -36
2020-01-04      73              52              -352
```

Where is my mistake and is there a better way of achieving my desired output?

Comment: `table_1.SUM(items)` is wrong, that would mean a function called `sum()` in the schema `table_1`. You want `sum(table_1.items)` and the same for `table_2.SUM(items_2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sum functions are wrong applied, and you should use group by:

```
select table_1.datestamp, sum(table_1.items), sum(table_2.items_2)
from table_1
left join table_2 on table_1.datestamp = table_2.datestamp
group by table_1.datestamp
```

**EDIT**
I answered too fast, my mistake, it would be better to do

```
select a.datestamp, sum(a.total), sum(b.total)
from (select datestamp, sum(items) as toatl
      from table_1
      group by datestamp) a
    join (select datestamp, sum(items_2) as total
      from table_2
      group by datestamp) b on a.datestamp = b.datestamp
group by a.datestamp
```

My first query is wrong because it multiplies the result. When you do the join you get the next result (for the date 2020-01-01):

```
2020-01-01      1       346
2020-01-01      33      346
2020-01-01      245     346
2020-01-01      55      346
2020-01-01      534     346
2020-01-01      35      346
2020-01-01      35      346
2020-01-01      1       3623
2020-01-01      33      3623
2020-01-01      245     3623
2020-01-01      55      3623
2020-01-01      534     3623
2020-01-01      35      3623
2020-01-01      35      3623
```

So the values in the first table get multiplied by 2 and the values in the second table get multiplied by 7

Comment: It's true but don't forget if there is a timestapm in table_2 that is not in table_1 it does not shown in your result.

Comment: I am getting the sums twice as big as they should for the first sum, and be for some reason. And the sums for table_2 is not correct as well.

Comment: `sum(table_1.items)` is x2 and `sum(table_2.items_2)` is x7 for some reason once the talbes get joined.

Comment: It worked, thanks, any idea why would the first one multiply the results by 2 and 7?

Comment: Yes, because when you do the join, you mix each row of the first table with each one of the second table, so if you have a date (2020-01-01) you get 14 rows (in your example), so that why table1 multiplies by 2 (14 rows in join  / 7 rows in table =2) and in table 2 multiplies by 7 (14 rows in join  / 2 rows in table = 7)